# Why does changing ListView.Sorting property erase all subitem images?

Tags: c#, image, listview, mfc, subitem

I'm using a ListView with extended style set to  `LVS_EX_SUBITEMIMAGES` to show small icons near every subitem (look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/OAKListView.aspx) article for more information). The problem is when I change the `Sorting` property  somewhere in code (without even actually sorting the list) it causes all images to disappear. Could anyone explain why this happens? Which events or messages are causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `sorting` property to Ascending or Descending will already apply the sorting to the list (source [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.sorting.aspx)). The `ListView.Sort()` function is to be used to perform your own item sorting in combination with the `ListViewItemSorter` property.

From what I read of the example you are refering to, you need to repaint the images after  sorting the items.